# 下記のように数値が色々ある場合、これを正規表現で一括選択する方法はないのでしょうか？

Tags: sublimetext

下記のように数値が色々ある場合、これを正規表現で一括選択する方法はないのでしょうか？
この属性の後に別の属性を一括追加したいです。

value="7"
value="8"

サブライムテキストを使っています。

value="."で一つ選択はできるのですが一括選択ができません。
また関係ない所のvalueが選択されても困るので、できればコントロールプラスDで一つ一つ目で確認しながらやりたいのですが、不可能でしょうか？

Comment: Sublime Text エディタ上での検索・置換に関するご質問ということであっていますでしょうか？　JavaScript 等で置換したいという話ではなく、エディタで編集するにあたって一気に置換したい、ということですよね。

Comment: そうです。サブライムテキストで行いたいです。また、関係ないところが選択されていないかを確認できればもっとありがたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

残念ながら、`ctrl+D`では正規表現を使えないと思います。

代わりに置換を使うといいと思います。
以下のように置換すると、`Replace All`で別の属性を一括で追加することができます。
この例では、", val=something"を後ろに追加しています。
Find:`value="(.)"`
Replace:`value="$1", val=something`

関係ない所のvalueが存在する場合は`Replace All`できないので、一つ一つFind→Replaceしていくしかないです...
でも一つ一つコピペしていくよりは、はるかに楽になるでしょう。

Comment: value="(.)"で、すべての数値のvalueを選択できました。ただコントロールDではできないようですね。対象物意外まで選択されてしまう事は、諦めるしかなさそうですね。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 対象以外のvalueというのがどういうものを指すのか分かりませんが、対象外となる文字列に規則性があるのであれば、それを除外するような正規表現を追加することで一括置換が可能になると思います。まぁ、根本的な解決策ではないですが...

Comment: もしくはそれを可能にしてしまうプラグインをあなたが作ってしまうのもいいかもしれません！

Comment: ありがとうございました。これ以上は無理そうですね。